# CloudFormation template - issue assigning S3 permissions

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Working on a CloudFormation template that consolidates CloudTrail logs from multiple accounts into a single S3 bucket. Attempting to set permissions on an S3 bucket so that each account writes to their own folder. The two last !Join lines are giving me grief.

```
MasterAccNum:
Type: String
Description: 12 digit account number without dashes.

ProdAccNum:
Type: String
Description: 12 digit account number without dashes.

Sid: AWSCloudTrailWrite
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      Action: s3:PutObject
      Resource: 
        - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'LoggingS3Bucket', /AWSCloudTrailLogs/, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', /*]]
        - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'LoggingS3Bucket', /AWSCloudTrailLogs/, !Ref 'MasterAccNum', /*]]
        - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'LoggingS3Bucket', /AWSCloudTrailLogs/, !Ref 'ProdAccNum', /*]]
```

I enter 12 digit account numbers for MasterAccNum and ProdAccNum parameters and end up with S3 permissions looking like this:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mycompanyname-is-cloudtrail-logs/AWSCloudTrailLogs/012345678901/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mycompanyname-is-cloudtrail-logs/AWSCloudTrailLogs//*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mycompanyname-is-cloudtrail-logs/AWSCloudTrailLogs//*"
```

The last two lines are missing parameters entered during stack launch

Comment: Is that the full template? not seeing `Parameters:` above the actual parameters. or `Resources:` for that matter.

Comment: Just a snippet; I defined two parameters MasterAccNum and ProdAccNum but when I tried to reference them latter in the template it doesn't work as expected. Most likely bad YAM in my !Join statements. Will post the entire template if needed.